# Error in installing pywrapcp package in Windows os

Tags: python, pip, package

Code to install `pywrapcp` package in python in Windows `x64`:
`pip install pywrapcp`

Output:

```
Error: Could not find a version That satisfies the requirement pywrapcp  
Error: No matching distribution found for pywrapcp
```

My pip version : `21.0.1`
How can I solve this error?

Comment: There is no such thing at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/pywrapcp/. What are you trying to install? Do you mean https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/constraint_solver/pywrapcp? It's not a separate package, it's a part of Google OR-Tools: See https://pypi.org/project/ortools/ and https://github.com/google/or-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pywrapcp`](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/constraint_solver/pywrapcp) is a part of [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization). To install run this:

```
pip install ortools
```

See the detailed instructions at https://developers.google.com/optimization/install

Comment: Yes Thank You for your help. It was exactly what i want !